# Why Listbox Multiple selection is not working on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a listbox with data from SQL DB. On Page Load,I want to select multiple items according to the data from my query result. It doesn't give me any errors and also not working.
Here is the code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack){

             DataTable userinfo = AppDataAccess.retrieveUsers(id);
                   foreach (DataRow row in userinfo.Rows)
            {
              string group = row["GroupNumber"].ToString();
                List<string> val = group.Split(',').ToList();

             if (val != null)
                    {
                        ListBox1.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;

                        //loop to select multiple items
                        foreach (string per in val)
                        {
                            if (ListBox1.Items.FindByValue(per.ToString()) != null)
                            {
                                ListBox1.Items.FindByValue(per.ToString()).Selected = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
             }



     }
 }
```

It doesn't give me any error and also not selecting any items.I try several ways and still not working. Any idea?

Comment: how do you fill the `ListBox1.Items` collection?

Comment: @Knaģis It binds with the data from database table.                            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="shrimpGpat" DataTextField="GroupName" DataValueField="GroupNumber" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>

Comment: Did you ensure that your code runs AFTER your ListBox is DataBound. From what I see, it seems doubtfull

Comment: @jbl That's I am not sure that too. If It is the problem,what is the alternative way to fix it? I am just jump into  CFML,PHP Zone to .Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this items election code from your PageLoad and put it in another method (say `SelectItems`)
Somewhere in your page you should have one or more `ListBox1.DataBind();` calls.
Put a call to SelectItems right after these `ListBox1.DataBind();` calls.

Also I guess your code could be written like this using Linq

```
public void SelectItems()
{
 ListBox1.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
 var userinfos = AppDataAccess.retrieveUsers(id);

 var val = userInfos.Rows.SelectMany(r=>r["GroupNumber"].ToString().Split(','))
    .Distinct().ToList()

  //loop to select multiple items // could also be converted to Linq. Not sure it would be useful
  foreach (string per in val)
      {
       if (ListBox1.Items.FindByValue(per.ToString()) != null)
          {
           ListBox1.Items.FindByValue(per.ToString()).Selected = true;
           }
        }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You could try it the other way around, loop all `ListItems` and set each `Selected` property:

```
foreach(DataRow row in userinfo.Rows)
{
    string group = row.Field<String>("GroupNumber");
    string[] vals = group.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach(ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        item.Selected = vals.Contains(item.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set `SelectionMode="Multiple"` for ListBox.

Comment: But OP has even set it programmatically as you can see in his code: `ListBox1.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;`

Comment: oh sorry i have not seen that.